# NCES style bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to highlight part of a stacked bar, as in this **NCES plot**^, to denote a subcategory?

[image]

^For reference, the plot is from the latest [Condition of Education report](http://nces.ed.gov/programs/coe/indicator_cnc.asp).

Comment: Technically, pretty anything is possible. An inset rectangle with a text annotation will likely be considerably work, though. Probably better to simply do three discrete segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned by @joran, all is possible with `ggplot2`, with some tips.
Here is a solution with fake data:

[image]

```
# Fake data
set.seed(3)
d1 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], y1 = sample(1:75, 5))
d1$y2 = 100 - d1$y1
d1$y3 = NA
for(i in 1:5)
{
  d1$y3[i] = sample(1:d1$y2[i],1)
}

df2 = melt(d1, id = "x")
ff = df2
ff$col1 = ff$value
ff$col1[ff$variable == "y3"] <- NA
ff$col2 = ff$value
ff$col2[ff$variable == "y2"] <- ff$col2[ff$variable == "y2"] -
    ff$col2[ff$variable == "y3"]

ff = merge(ff, d1[,c("x", "y1", "y2" ,"y3")], by = "x")

ff$variable = factor(ff$variable, levels = c("y1", "y2", "y3"))
ff = ff[order(ff$variable),]

# Plot
ggplot(ff) + 
geom_bar(aes(x = as.numeric(x)-0.2, y = col1, fill = variable), stat = "identity", width = 0.4) + 
geom_bar(aes(x = as.numeric(x)+0.2, y = col2, fill = variable), stat = "identity", width = 0.4) + 
scale_x_continuous(name = "x", breaks = as.numeric(unique(ff$x)), labels = levels(ff$x)) + 
theme_bw() + 
geom_text(aes(x=as.numeric(x)+0.2, y = 100-y3/2, label = y3)) + 
geom_text(aes(x=as.numeric(x), y = y1/2, label = y1)) +  
geom_text(aes(x=as.numeric(x), y = y1 + (y2-y3)/2, label = y2)) + 
geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(x), xend = as.numeric(x), y = 100-y3, yend = 100)) + 
geom_segment(aes(x = as.numeric(x), xend = as.numeric(x)+0.4, y = 100-y3, yend = 100-y3))
```

Answer (score 2):

For fun I tried to do this in fewer lines with classic R. See what you think
[image: base R plot]

```
# Fake d1
set.seed(3)
d1 <- data.frame(x = LETTERS[1:5], y1 = sample(1:75, 5))
d1$y2 = 100 - d1$y1
d1$y3 = NA
for(i in 1:5)
{
  d1$y3[i] = sample(1:d1$y2[i],1)
}


ux <- length(unique(d1$x))
par(list(mar=c(2.5,2.5,0.2,0.2), mgp=c(1.5,0.5,0),las=1, cex.axis=0.8, cex.lab=0.8))
plot(c(0.5,ux+.5), c(0,100), type="n", axes=FALSE, xlab="Year", ylab="Percent")
axis(1,at=1:ux,labels=d1$x)
axis(2,at=seq(0,100,20))
rect(1:ux-0.4, 0, (1:ux)+0.4, d1$y1, col = "green")
rect(1:ux-0.4, d1$y1, (1:ux)+0.4, d1$y1 + d1$y2, col = "lightgreen")
rect(1:ux,     100 , (1:ux)+0.4, 100 - d1$y3, col = "lightblue")
text(1:ux, y= d1$y1/2, d1$y1, cex=0.8)
text(1:ux, y= d1$y1 + 10, d1$y2, cex=0.8)
text(1:ux+0.2, y= 100 - d1$y3/2, d1$y3, cex=0.8)
```

it's annoying that I have to have the call to par in there so it isn't so ugly. But once you have your par call worked out you can just use it.